# hfl.argentina.Hasar Exception: 'Se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

El error me aparece en cuando intento depurar el programa, el error esta en la linea de codigo de la IP 192.168.0.30, como lo puedo solucionar

```
public void handle()
        {
            HasarImpresoraFiscalRG3561 fiscalDevice = new HasarImpresoraFiscalRG3561();
            fiscalDevice.conectar("192.168.0.30");
            
            List<Encabezado> encabezados = Encabezado.FiscalesImprimibles();

            foreach (var encabezado in encabezados)
            {
                fiscalPrint(fiscalDevice, encabezado);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Si especificas el error que te sale te podríamos ayudar mucho mejor

Comment: El error es el del titulo, osea "hfl.argentina.Hasar Exception: 'Se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación'"

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que dicha ip es la correcta? Si hay algo más que debamos saber que nos ayude a responderte agrégalo a la pregunta por favor.

Comment: Ese es el unico error, vere si es correcta la IP

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que especificar el tiempo de espera. Ejemplo:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
    p.conectar("192.168.10.130");
                p.establecerTiempoDeEspera(10000);
                p.establecerTiempoDeEsperaLecturaEscritura(15000);
   }
```